# Should I use px or percentage?

Tags: css, percentage, pixel

So I'm making a tumblr theme, and I have it pretty much finished. Except I need to make it fit all screen resolutions. My own laptop screen is pretty small, so I styled it to look good on mine -- but when I asked other people about it, they said it was too far to the left, and that the pagination buttons were off.

I did some looking around, and I saw a bunch of people saying it's better to use percents than pixels when trying to make a website fit all screen resolutions.

Here are some snippets of the code.

This is the sidebar:

```
 #sidebar {
           width: 260px;
           padding: 10px;
           border: 10px double #D15FEE;
           background: {color:Sidebar background} url({image:Sidebar background});
           top: 90px;
           position: fixed;
           left: 5%;

       }
```

This is for the posts themselves:

```
       #posts {
           background: {color:Post background} url({image:Post background});
           width: 510px;
           padding: 27px;
           margin-top: 50px;
           margin-left: 36%;
           border: 4px solid #F7B3DA;
           padding-bottom: 20px;


       }
```

And this is for the pagination:

```
  #footerd {
        position: relative;
        right: 35%;
        text-align: right;


    }
```

I thought that would solve my problem, but after looking at my theme on my sister's laptop, some things were *still* out of place.

Can anyone give me any advice on which is the best to use, and how to fix this

Oh, also, [here](http://demonhetero.tumblr.com) is my theme. (*Please* don't comment on the actual contents of that blog...)

Comment: For fluid layouts `%` is good. For adaptive layouts, you could make use of `px` with `media queries`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `px` when you want something to be EXACTLY a particular size every time.

But you should use Percentage when you want something to resize depending on the browser size. Percentage can help make a website a lot more easier to access when using smaller screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You should use % if you want your site to look good on a smaller as well as larger viewports.

eg. You give a 100px margin-left for your laptop of 1450px width and the content will look perfect adjusted, but for a laptop of 1020px the structure might look distorted.

So prefer using % it makes the work much easier, only when there is something that is quite small eg just 5px then prefer px, but something large value prefer %,

Answer (score 0):

When making things "responsive" or fit all screen sizes you want to use percentage and look in to using media queries to specify what the view should look like for that screen size

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to look good on multiple sites, use percentage when you are setting something like the width of the sidebar. So if the width is 25%, it will take 25 percent of a laptop screen and but will also take 25% of a smaller screen.